# Set Grid Column/Row width/Height dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, code-behind

I need to create a WPF grid dynamically from code behind. This is going okay and I can do it so that I set the content widths but what I need to do is set them so that when i resize the window the controls are re sized dynamically

```
var col = new ColumnDefinition();
col.Width = new System.Windows.GridLength(200);
grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
```

This will produce XAML

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

But what I need is to use a * or question mark ie.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

But the WidthValue does not support a * or question mark a when creating from code behind ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could specify it like this:

For auto sized columns:

```
GridLength.Auto
```

For star sized columns:

```
new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star)
```

Answer (score 8):

There is 3 types of setting Width to Grid ColumnDefinitions:

**For Percentage Column:**

```
 yourGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
```

In xaml:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
```

**For Pixel Column**

```
yourGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Pixel);
yourGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(10);
```

In xaml:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
```

**For Auto Column**

```
yourGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = GridLength.Auto;
```

In xaml:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

I think this can help:

for Auto Column:

```
ColumnDefinition cd = new ColumnDefinition();
cd.Width = GridLength.Auto;
```

or for proportion grid length:

```
ColumnDefinition cd = new ColumnDefinition();
cd.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
```

or look at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength.aspx
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridunittype.aspx

Greez
Shounbourgh

Answer (score -1):

A lot of explanations have already been provided by others. GridLength syntax is the same for both `RowDefinations` and `ColumnDefinations`. Sharing colour code syntax for quick and easy understanding
[image]

Comment: Please consider the usefulness of your answer to all users before posting, including those who are unable to view images.